# Jquery - View large image within a browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a list of large images that I'd like to show within a browser overlay.  The images are much larger that the browser viewport and the user needs to be able to navigate around them to view details.

I'd ideally like to use a Jquery plugin that could act as a PDF viewer - i.e. you can zoom in and out of the image and scroll around it.

Does anyone have any suggestions of how to code this or of any plug-ins I could use?

Thanks for your help.

Paul

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Google Maps API with a custom image map type. Similar to what maplib.net is doing.

Answer (score 1):

**You might want to take a look at [Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/).**

It has support for resizing, clipping, scrolling and pretty much every document format you can think of.